# Color a Graph Black & White

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a graph where each edge (u, v) has a couple of signs that symbolise how to color the vertexes u and v. For example: an edge has the couple (b, w)- that means that u will be colored In black and v will be colored in white.
The thing is that each edge can have more than one option for coloring its vertexes.

I need to find, in not to much time, if there is a legal coloring (matches the options) or not, and if there is I need to give the legal coloring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try googling ? Graph coloring is a common algorithm problem and there are various well known methods

Comment: Would you define "legal" as follows? Given vertices *u,v,w*  and edges *X = (u,v)* and *Y = (v,w)*, and coloring *Xc = (c1,c2), Yc = (c3,c4)* then *c2 = c3*?

Comment: Also, how is your data represented i.e. what's the format of your input?

Answer (score 1):

This is a disguised version of 2SAT. Let each vertex v give rise to a variable x_v. Let 1 be white and 0 be black. To exclude the possibility, e.g., that v is white and w is black,  add ((NOT x_v) OR x_w) to the list of clauses ANDed together. Unlike its higher-arity cousins, [2SAT is known to have linear-time algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability).

Comment: hey man, in understood the main idea and i know the 2sat problem but i don't exactly ubderstand your answer. i'd be glad if you could explain a bit further.

Comment: @user76508 Sorry, but if you knew about 2SAT, then the odds from my point of view that this is homework went up dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by @zepp93 you need to use the chromatic polynomials. Here the chromtic number(the number of colors) is 2. Depending on the graph you can devise the chromatic Polynomial. Find it out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "legal coloring" but you might wanna look at  [Chromatic Polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial). The number of ways of coloring a certain graph with `n` nodes can be found. Since you have two colors,set the chromatic number as 2 and substitute it in your chromatic polynomial equation which you have to find out for your graph. There are certain tutorials where you can learn how to do that and I'm sure if you try to Google,you'll find it. A great book on Graph Theory,written by Frank Hararay is available online. Check it out.